# Distinct of values in SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

Example table:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | content             |
+----+---------------------+
| 1  | item1, item5, item6 |
| 2  | item2, item5, item8 |
+----+---------------------+
```

I want to use `SELECT DISTINCT` but within the `conntent`'s values. So after using some unknown command, I should get this: `item1, item2, item5, item6, item8`. Is it possible by any way?

**Why do I ask something like that?**

I'm making eshop, where a company will sell a tea bags. And tea bags have their "structure". Different products can have common, for example, apple flavor. And I want to get these commons so I can make dynamic filter based on these information.

Comment: Fix your data structure to use a junction table with one row per `id` and per `item`.  Then your query will not be hard.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know about it, but I have't make this in the start of project and there was no filter for that, so there were simply textual contents. So I was wondering about something like that.

Comment: With the current structure you would have to use `LIKE` which is a text search.  It will do a full table scan for every search term so the queries will take a long time to run.  This is likely unacceptable in a web application where users are sensitive to even small additional wait time.  You'll need to fix the data structure as Gordon indicated to get an acceptable performance.

Comment: Ok, all I wanted to know was, if it would not be hard to go this way. So ok, rebuild table.